# $A^{64}=A^{27}=I$, prove $A=I$

Tags: matrices

$A^{64}=A^{27}=I$, prove $A=I$.

I tried finding the eigenvalues of A, by factoring $A^{64}-I$ but this method is too long. I'm not really sure what to do, I thought of showing $A$ is similar to $I$ but I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: hint: consider $\mu = \min\{n \ge 1 : A^n=I\}$...

Comment: A = A^1(A^(64))^8 = A^513 = (A^27)^19 = 1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since $A^{64}=I$, $A$ is invertible and $(A^{-1})^{64} = I$. Also, since $64$ and $27$ are coprime, you can find a [linear combination of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) yielding $1$, namely $19\cdot 27 - 8 \cdot 64 = 1$.

Then $A = A^{19\cdot 27 - 8 \cdot 64} = (A^{27})^{19}\cdot (A^{-64})^{8} = I^{19} \cdot I^8 = I$.

Comment: How is $A$ invertible?

Comment: @SeanRoberson what is its determinant?

Comment: @SeanRoberson $A^{63} \cdot A = I$

Answer (score 5):

A small elaboration on charmd‘s answer: we don't need to use Bezout's identity and take matrix inverses. Euclidean algorithm is perfectly sufficient: since $A^{64}=A^{27}=I$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
&A^{10}=A^{10}I^2=A^{10}(A^{27})^2=A^{64}=I\\
\Rightarrow\ &A^7=A^7I^2=A^7(A^{10})^2=A^{27}=I\\
\Rightarrow\ &A^3=A^3I=A^3A^7=A^{10}=I\\
\Rightarrow\ &A=AI^2=A(A^3)^2=A^7=I.\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 4):

A "constructive" approach. $$I=A^{64}=(A^{27})^2A^{10}\Rightarrow\\I=A^{10}\Rightarrow\\I=A^{27}=(A^{10})^2A^{7}=A^7\Rightarrow\\I=A^7=A^{10}A^{-3}=A^{-3}\Rightarrow\\A^4A^{-3}=A=I$$